# string Append function in C

Tags: c, string, memory, allocation

I want to create a string append function, but when I want to print the function out it crash. I debugged it but I cannot find what could be the problem.

```
struct string {
    size_t length;
    size_t allocated;
    char* data;
};
string* Init(char* str) {
    string* s = malloc(sizeof(string));
    size_t strLen = strlen(str);
    s->data = (char*)malloc(strLen*2); //allocate 2x of the length
    memcpy(s->data,str,strLen);
    s->data[strLen] = '\0';
    s->length = strLen;
    s->allocated = 2*strLen;
    return s;
}
void AppendBack(string* str, string* new) {
    if(str->allocated < str->length + new->length) { //allocate more
        char* data = (char*)realloc(strGet(str),str->allocated*2);
        str->allocated = str->allocated*2;
        str->data = data;
        if(str->allocated < str->length + new->length) { //need more allocation
            AppendBack(str,new);
        }
    }
    str->length = str->length + new->length;
    for(int i = new->length; i >= 0; --i) {
        str->data[str->length - i] = new->data[new->length - i];
    }
    str->data[str->length] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    string* a = Init("abc");
    string* b = Init("1234fedfsdffghjkjhgfds3ghjk7345678juhzbfsdfsd");
    AppendBack(a,b);
    strPrint(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Edited code:

```
    char* strGet(string* str) {
        return str->data;
    }
    void strPrint(string* str) {
        printf("%s",strGet(str));
    }
```

I am sorry becuase I missed part of my code.

Comment: Where are `strGet` and `strPrint`? Recursively calling `AppendBack` and letting the code after the call run won't end well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs:

1. You need to allocate an extra byte for the terminating zero.
2. You need to return after calling `AppendBack` recursively or you corrupt the string.

Here's working code:

```
void AppendBack(string* str, string* new) {
    if(str->allocated < (str->length + new->length + 1)) { // NOTE: +1
        char* data = (char*)realloc(str->data,str->allocated*2); // removed call to strGet
        str->allocated = str->allocated*2;
        str->data = data;
        if(str->allocated < (str->length + new->length + 1)) { // NOTE: +1
            AppendBack(str,new);
            return; // NOTE: return here
        }
    }
    str->length = str->length + new->length;
    for(int i = new->length; i >= 0; --i) {
        str->data[str->length - i] = new->data[new->length - i];
    }
    str->data[str->length] = '\0'; // See? You need an extra byte for this
}
```

I removed the call to `strGet` because you didn't show us that code.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, strGet just "convert" string data to char*

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you handling the allocation of a null terminator very well.  Your `length` field does not count the null terminator, so neither should your `allocated` field either, otherwise your calculations may be off at times.  But your `malloc()` calls need to account for the null terminator.

Also, you are not exiting from `AppendBack()` after performing the recursion.  I would suggest getting rid of the recursion altogether and just calculate the needed allocation size in an iterative loop instead.

Try something more like this:

```c
typedef struct string {
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;
    char* data;
} string;

string* Init(char* str) {
    string* s = (string*) malloc(sizeof(string));
    if (!s) return NULL;
    size_t strLen = strlen(str);
    s->length = strLen;
    s->capacity = strLen*2;
    s->data = (char*) malloc(s->capacity+1); //allocate 2x of the length, plus a null terminator
    if (!s->data) {
        free(s);
        return NULL;
    }
    memcpy(s->data, str, strLen);
    s->data[strLen] = '\0';
    return s;
}

void Cleanup(string* str) {
    if (str) free(str->data);
    free(str);
}

void AppendBack(string* str, string* str2) {
    size_t newLen = str->length + str2->length;
    if (str->capacity < newLen) { //allocate more
        size_t cap = str->capacity;
        do {
            cap *= 2;
        } while (cap <= newLen);
        char* data = (char*) realloc(str->data, cap+1);
        if (!data) return;
        str->data = data;
        str->capacity = cap;
    }
    memcpy(&str->data[str->length], str2->data, str2->length);
    str->data[newLen] = '\0';
    str->length = newLen;
}

void strPrint(string *str) {
    printf("%s", str->data);
}

int main() {
    string* a = Init("abc");
    string* b = Init("1234fedfsdffghjkjhgfds3ghjk7345678juhzbfsdfsd");
    AppendBack(a,b);
    strPrint(a);
    Cleanup(b);
    Cleanup(a);
    return 0;
}
```